# How do I shorten a for loop with arithmetic inside?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I've been wondering if I can shorten a for loop with arithmetic inside of it
Here is my code:

```
n = int(input("n: "))
string = ''

for i in range(n):
    string += input()
```

I want to make it a one line code, Is it possible?

**This is what I tried**:

```
[string+=input() for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you really want, you can do:

```
string = ''.join(input() for _ in range(int(input("n: "))))
```